# How to ensure privacy and safety in hotels of India?

Tags: india, hotels, sex, privacy

I do a moderate number of travels with my girlfriend and use good hotels (with a minimum 3 star rating) to stay for single/multiple days.

We feel insecure to do intimate tasks such as foreplay, sex etc., due to the fear of hidden cameras and spying.

I am not getting any proper solution regarding this over the internet. Are there any **really working** hidden camera detectors to help out in such situations? What steps I have to take to ensure our privacy and safety to do such intimate tasks in hotels?

Comment: Consider turning off the lights. Even if they use infrared cameras, the resulting pictures won't have much market value and it will be hard to identify individuals.

Comment: The whole thing about spying hotel cameras seems to be more urban myth than fact based. There is a lot of rumors and discussion on forums, but it's very difficult to find a confirmed case from a credible news source. You may be over thinking this. It would be highly illegal in most countries and the hotel has little to gain and a lot to loose. There are certainly a lot of "hidden camera" videos on adult web sites, but these are almost all staged. It's not a real hidden camera.

Comment: Some real life cases. Here's one. https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/crime/11839396/Travelodge-guest-finds-spy-camera-hidden-in-shower-at-Oxford-hotel.html

Comment: Before we invented centrally heated bedrooms people used to have sex under the bedclothes.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a question of your privacy, rest assured, decent hotels have a reputation to maintain and will not do anything to tarnish it.

Now imagine a hotel concierge or hotel staff who decides to act funny and place cameras hidden in your room. This can happen from the shadiest to the most elite class of hotel you might choose. Basically there is no guarantee of it. It is best if you opt for good rated hotels or even Airbnbs and take a look around once you enter your rooms.